0.0 loss function while training transformer
I'm trying to complete Kaggle competition
I created some sort of transformer model where I train 2 models on keywords column and on hashtags (which I extracted from text column). Here is a model for keywords classification:
vocab_size = 6000
maxlen = 2
embed_dim = 32
num_heads = 2
ff_dim = 64
# regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.005)
regularizer = None
num_of_dense_layers = 2
num_of_transformer_blocks = 2
dropout_rate = 0.1


input_keyword = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name="keyword")

text_vec_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    vocab_size,
    output_sequence_length=maxlen
)
text_vec_layer.adapt(x_train["text"])

embedding_layer_keyword = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)

# Keyword model
x = text_vec_layer(input_keyword)
x = embedding_layer_keyword(x)

for i in range(num_of_transformer_blocks):
    transformer_block_keyword = TransformerBlock(
        embed_dim,
        num_heads,
        ff_dim,
        rate=dropout_rate
    )
    x = transformer_block_keyword(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)

for _ in range(num_of_dense_layers):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

keyword_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_keyword, outputs=outputs)

x_train_keyword = x_train[x_train["keyword"] != ""]
y_train_keyword = y_train[x_train["keyword"] != ""]

x_val_keyword = x_val[x_val["keyword"] != ""]
y_val_keyword = y_val[x_val["keyword"] != ""]

lr_scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    factor=0.3,
    patience=1,
    min_lr=1e-6,
    mode="min",
)
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.AdamW(weight_decay=0.001)

keyword_model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
keyword_model.fit(
    x_train_keyword["keyword"],
    y_train_keyword,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(
        x_val_keyword["keyword"],
        y_val_keyword
    ),
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb, lr_scheduler],
)

And also here is a model for hashtags classification:
vocab_size = 6000
maxlen = 2
embed_dim = 32
num_heads = 2
ff_dim = 32
# regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.005)
regularizer = None
num_of_dense_layers = 2
num_of_transformer_blocks = 2
dropout_rate = 0.2


input_hashtag = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name="hashtags")

text_vec_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    vocab_size,
    output_sequence_length=maxlen
)
text_vec_layer.adapt(x_train["hashtags"])  # hashtags

embedding_layer_hashtag = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)

# Keyword model
x = text_vec_layer(input_hashtag)
x = embedding_layer_hashtag(x)

for i in range(num_of_transformer_blocks):
    transformer_block_hashtag = TransformerBlock(
        embed_dim,
        num_heads,
        ff_dim,
        rate=dropout_rate
    )
    x = transformer_block_hashtag(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)

for _ in range(num_of_dense_layers):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

hashtag_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_hashtag, outputs=outputs)

x_train_hashtag = x_train[x_train["hashtags"] != ""]
y_train_hashtag = y_train[x_train["hashtags"] != ""]

x_val_hashtag = x_val[x_val["hashtags"] != ""]
y_val_hashtag = y_val[x_val["hashtags"] != ""]

lr_scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    factor=0.3,
    patience=1,
    min_lr=1e-6,
    mode="min",
)
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=20, restore_best_weights=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.AdamW(weight_decay=0.001)

hashtag_model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
hashtag_model.fit(
    x_train["hashtags"],
    y_train,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(
        x_val["hashtags"],
        y_val
    ),
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb, lr_scheduler],
)

So then I use these 2 models in my main transformer:
vocab_size = 6000
maxlen = 50
embed_dim = 32
num_heads = 3
ff_dim = 32
# regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.005)
regularizer = None
num_of_dense_layers = 2
num_of_transformer_blocks = 2
dropout_rate = 0.5
keyword_model.trainable = False
hashtag_model.trainable = False

text_vec_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    vocab_size,
    output_sequence_length=maxlen
)
text_vec_layer.adapt(x_train["text"])

embedding_layer_text = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)

input_text = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name="text")

x_text = text_vec_layer(input_text)
embedding_text = embedding_layer_text(x_text)
x_text = embedding_text

for i in range(num_of_transformer_blocks):
    transformer_block_text = TransformerBlock(
        embed_dim,
        num_heads,
        ff_dim,
        rate=dropout_rate,
        regularizer=regularizer,
    )
    x_text = transformer_block_text(x_text)
    if num_of_transformer_blocks != (i + 1):
        x_text = x_text + embedding_text

x_text = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x_text)
# x_text = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x_text)

x_keyword_output = keyword_model(input_keyword)
x_hashtags_output = hashtag_model(input_hashtag)

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x_text, x_keyword_output, x_hashtags_output])

for _ in range(num_of_dense_layers):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

transformer = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_text, input_hashtag, input_keyword], outputs=outputs)

lr_scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    factor=0.3,
    patience=1,
    min_lr=1e-6,
    mode="min",
)
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, restore_best_weights=True, mode="min")
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.AdamW(weight_decay=0.001)

transformer.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
history = transformer.fit(
    {"text": x_train["text"], "hashtags": x_train["hashtags"], "keyword": x_train["keyword"]},
    y_train,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(
        {"text": x_val["text"], "hashtags": x_val["hashtags"], "keyword": x_val["keyword"]},
        y_val
    ),
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb, lr_scheduler],
)

It seems like everything is ok, but when I'm training my main model I'm receiving 0.0000e+00 loss and val_loss:
Epoch 1/100
277/277 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 31s 49ms/step - accuracy: 0.5305 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6494 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - learning_rate: 0.0010

I'm using sparse categorical cross entropy as loss function. I'm trying to wonder if there is a problem with model architecture or what...
